# The way to create a new pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I am trying to create a new pointer by using  two ways, do they mean the same?

```
int* ptn;
int* ptn(nullptr);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am trying to create a new pointer by using two ways, do they mean the same?

No, they don't - or at least, not always.

If those variables are declared at block scope, the first one will just give you an uninitialized pointer, while the second one will initialize the pointer to a null pointer value. So in the first case:

```
int main()
{
    int* ptn; // This gives you an uninitialized pointer...
    if (ptn == nullptr) // ...so this is UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR!
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you were to use the value of `ptn` anyhow before initializing it to some value, you would hit **undefined behavior**.

On the other hand, the two declarations would be the equivalent if they were at namespace scope, since `ptr` would have *static storage duration*, and would be zero-initialized anyway:

```
int* ptn; // This pointer has static storage duration, will be zero-initialized...
int main()
{
    if (ptn == nullptr) // ...so no undefined behavior here!
    {
        // This will be entered...
    }
}
```

Per paragraph 8.5/10 of the C++11 Standard:

> [ Note: Every object of static storage duration is zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization
>   takes place. In some cases, additional initialization is done later. —end note ]

Comment: What if those two declarations are at namespace scope? Is the first one still uninitialized?

Comment: @Nawaz Thinking outside the braces.

Comment: @Ming: Glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 1):

They aren't the same;  the first line maynot initialize the pointer to any value, and will be garbage, although it is usually predefined garbage in debug modes, something like `0xcdcdcdcd`, so you can identify locations where you attempt to access an uninitialized pointer; different for pointers that are on the stack vs the heap. The 2nd line will initialize to the new c++ version of a null pointer (previously just '0'); go with the 2nd, either as you have it, or `int * ptn = nullptr`, which I find is more common.

Answer (score 0):

No, always use the second form!

The first one is an uninitialized pointer, that can point to some random place in the memory and accessing it can cause an access violation amongst other crazy behaviors.

the second will initialize the pointer to null as it should.

Answer (score 0):

int *ptn; is a pointer that is not pointing to anything, or pointing to garbage. int *ptn(nullptr); is being initialized at compile time to the null value.